# Attributes of God in Spinoza’s “Ethics”

Tags: metaphysics, theology, spinoza

In Spinoza’s *Ethics*, he remarks that God/Nature has infinitely many attributes. However, in the *Ethics*, he only identifies and discusses two of these attributes: thought and extension, which account for the correspondence between the human mind and human body.

Does Spinoza ever state elsewhere what he thinks some of the other attributes of God/Nature might be? Have any historical Spinozists speculated about these additional attributes?

Comment: See [Spinoza’s Theory of Attributes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spinoza-attributes/)

Comment: Spinoza claims that we can perceive two attributes only, and even "proves" it. On Bennett's interpretation, "infinity of attributes" should be translated as "totality of attributes", and the  two are the whole "totality". In the Short Treatise Spinoza discusses the more traditional "attributes" of God, omnipotence, eternality, immutability, and infinity, but classifies them as only *propria* "*because they are nothing but Adjectives which cannot be understood without their Substantives. I.e., without them God would indeed not be God; but still, he is not God through them*".

Comment: It would depend ... on what Spinoza's God is,  oui? Plus, Spinoza seems like a very practical man, his poverty and isolation notwithstanding.

Answer (score -1):

(Using the Curley translation)

> VI: By God I understand a being absolutely infinite, that is, a substance consisting of an infinity of attributes, of which each expresses an eternal and infinite essence

The original Latin has "substantium constantem infinitis attributis" for "a substance consisting of an infinity of attributes".

So I don't think it's fair to say that Spinoza is defining God as having infinitely many attributes. In those days, infinity didn't have the quantitative meaning that it has today. It was mainly used when talking about God, with a *qualitative* meaning of "having no limits". I don't think it would have sounded as odd to contemporary readers as it does to us today.

So the two attributes that he discusses, thought and extension, are both infinite. That means that they do not limit each other, or they can exist in the same place. These are the only two such attributes. @Conifold points out that elsewhere Spinoza predicates God as omnipotent, eternal, immutability, etc. But these qualities do not have the same relationship to God as thought and extension, which are *constitutive* of God, or God is what He is through them.

Comment: Aristotle was the first to distinguish these two terms - the all and the infinite ...

Comment: Can you explain why the majority of texts, including the SEP, an online scholarly resource specifically state that Spinoza declared God, the infinite substance (as in unlimited) has an infinite number of attributes. Amd consider too that Spinoza got his definition of God from Aquinas who got it from Ibn Sinna where in Islam Allah is said to have ninety nine names?

Comment: -1, Spinoza explicitly defines his terms, all from the "Ethics" (1677): Def IV defines attribute as an essential quality (like extension or thought), Prop. VIII explicitly states that attributes are distinct from modifications, and that each substance is infinite in it's attribute, Prop. IX, the more attributes (not modifications), the more reality, Prop. XI, there is a single substance with an infinity of attributes, God. See: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3800/3800-h/3800-h.htm

Comment: The claim that each attribute (extension and thought) are in-themselves infinite is already addressed in Prop. VIII, when he is speaking of a plurality of merely infinite substances. This shifts in Prop. XI where he fuses them into one absolutely infinite substance, God.

Comment: @Hokon I don't understand how this relates to what I said. I do not believe he specifies a quantitative meaning of the word infinite.